# Unlock an existing functionality after successful completion of InAppPurchase Process

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I'm looking at in-app purchases.

Essentially all the content is there and I just want an in-app purchase that lets the user purchase an item, and upon successful completion of the purchase will unlock an existing functionality.

I only need to unlock existing content.

Are there any plugins to allow this kind of thing?

Comment: When down voted, please comment here.

Comment: @Aarti: What did I write different? I just showed same way to unlock your features and thats NSUserDefaults. `dlackty` has written the same. And in first place if you were  not satisfied, why did you accept my answer first?

Comment: Don't get angry.... I'm working on it. Thanks for your kind reply.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When user successfully complete the purchase, your program will receive a delegate callback of

```
- (void)completeTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction;
```

and then you can record this transaction and post a `NSNotification` to notify other objects in your app to unlock some premium functionalities.

Also, you can store values in `NSUserDefaults` for next time to decide whether the functionality is unlocked.

Here is a sample code as reference.

```
- (void)completeTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
  NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  [userDefaults setBool:YES forKey:@"proVersionEnabled"];
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"proVersionEnabledNotification" object:nil];

  [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
}
```

Comment: Please don't create duplicate answer. Look around on other answers before you create your own. An idea is what actually matters.

Comment: It's not a duplicate answer, this is the first answer that directly answers the question asked in a concise way, including relevant code snippets, and without relying on a link to a blog that may not exist when other people come to look at this question a year or two in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very generalized.

You need to be more specific. After successful transaction you just can use NSUserDefaults value or iOS Keychain to get value of a flag and unlock particular feature of your app.

Also I have a tutorial which could help you with this

http://nixsolutions.com/blog/development/iphone/in-app-purchase-tutorial/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just set a bool in the user defaults if the premium content was puchased and check that bool to decide if you do or don't show the premium content.